# How to call functions from different base class

Tags: python

Based on my limited Python knowledge, I have generated the following code snippet:

```
#import statements skipped
class DTestWrapper(BaseA if inLinux else unittest.TestCase):

    def setUpDTest(self):
        if inLinux:
            super(BaseA , self).setUpTestCase()
        else:
            super(unittest.TestCase, self).setUp()

    def tearDownDTest(self):
        if inLinux:
            super(BaseA ,self).tearDownTestCase()
        else:
            super(unittest.TestCase,self).tearDown()
```

**Some background:**
`BaseA` is a customized class that is used to beautify the test output into a table. It has member functions `setUpTestCase`, `tearDownTestCase` and many others.

**What I want to do**:
I want to call different `setUp` and `tearDown` functions for my own class `DTestWrapper` based on different platforms as shown in the above code. When it is running on Linux, I would like to use `BaseA` `setUp` and `tearDown` functions; otherwise, I would like to use functions from python `unittest.TestCase`. I have another class `D` that inherits from `DTestWrapper`, it will override the `setUpDTest` method, but currently it is simply empty for testing purpose.

**Question:**
When I ran the above code snippet, it seems that `setUp` or `setUpTestCase` are not called (tests all failed, they should not if they are called correctly). 
My question is:

**How could I call different `setUp` functions in `DTestWrapper`? Is this even possible to do?**

Since I am learning, any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I will remove that now.

Comment: Why do you want to run `setUp` on one platform and `setUpTestCase` on another? Those methods have entirely different roles.

Comment: @user2357112 I understand. It is a long story for why, simply put, we don't have other options in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super()` needs the **current** class to base off the search for a parent:

```
class DTestWrapper(BaseA if inLinux else unittest.TestCase):
    def setUpDTest(self):
        parent_method = 'setUpTestCase' if inLinux else 'setUp'
        getattr(super(DTestWrapper, self), parent_method)()

    def tearDownDTest(self):
        parent_method = 'tearDownTestCase' if inLinux else 'tearDown'
        getattr(super(DTestWrapper, self), parent_method)()
```

You may want to match the `BaseA` method names with the `unittest.TestCase` methods and save yourself the extra `if` testing there. Simple aliases would do; `BaseA.tearDown = BaseA.tearDownTestCase`, for example.

`super()` needs the current class to determine the correct Method Resolution Order, which depends entirely on the combination and order of base classes. If you give it a base class start off from instead, then `super()` will skip any methods on that base class as it must assume that that base class is the parent instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would try and rename your custom  method to simply `setUp` and `tearDown`, if thats's possible.

This way, once your class has been instanciated (subclassing either `unittest.TestCase` or `BaseA` depending on your `inLinux` variable), the right method will automagically be called, without the need to redefine them.

if you do need to extend them, then a simple

```
class DTestWrapper(BaseA if inLinux else unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(DTestWrapper, self).setUp()
        # your custom logic

    def tearDown(self):
        super(DTestWrapper, self).tearDown()
        # your custom logic
```

should do.